# How to access the sharepoint list in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

I have installed `sharepoint 2010` with backend `sql server 2008 R2` database name(wss_content). Now in my sharepoint site I have createed a sharepoint list( eg,customer). Now I want to access that list in the database(wss_content).

How can I access it?, and where can I see that list in wss_content.
Because I'm not able to see the list in the sql database.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think that MS allows direct query through sql for sharepoint. Why you need that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent of the SharePoint list in the SQL Database - even though it's there. **BUT you should never ever go into the SharePoint database and query for information** - you'll likley get things wrong or mess things up.

Tell us what you need instead and we'll sort you out with the correct way to do it.